# how to close a browser having pdf inside it

Tags: javascript

i have an browser with pdf which is opened on clicking "viewPDF" button in the main page of an asp.net and c#.net application.

On clicking the "viewPdf" button i am opening the pdf in the browser using the javascript as below:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function openpdf()
    {
        var  pdfobj= window.open('epcrpdf.aspx');
    }
</script>
```

in the design page.

```
<input id="btnTakeAction"
       class="Button" 
       type="button" value="View Pdf" 
       onclick="javscript:openpdf();">
```

The problem is i also have a log out button in the mainpage, on cliking the log out button i have to close the childwindows like the browser containing pdf.

when i try to close the browser containing using javscript as below i face a problem of "Access is denied".

```
pdfobj.close();
```

but other browsers which does not contain pdf gets closed with out any error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has worked for me:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var wnd = null;
        function openPdf() {
            wnd = window.open('test.pdf');
        }

        function closePdf() {
            if (wnd != null) {
                wnd.close();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <input type="button" name="open" value="Open" onclick="openPdf();" />
        <input type="button" name="close" value="Close" onclick="closePdf();" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me for the exact same problem in IE8, though it seems to work in Chrome. Might be due to changes in the last 4 years.