# How can window.closed = true, when the window is open?

Tags: javascript, html, popup, window.open

I am stepping through code, and I realized I cannot close a window, because the DispHTMLWindow2 object close property is still to true.

```
    if(winObject.closed != true)
       winObject.close();
```

The problem is winObject.closed == true, and the window is clearly open.

Any ideas where I can look to figure this out?

Thanks,
Grae

UPDATE:  I realize this problem may have to do with an embedded PDF.

Comment: IE 8, the popup window is just a PDF file.

Comment: If I don't find answer in a few minutes I will try to make a testcase.

Comment: It could be the embedded PDF - I don't know. You would have to test. 
If that is the reason, I would put the PDF as a 100% wide, 100% tall IFRAME into a normal HTML document.

Comment: If you find something out, you can answer your own question so at least we'll have a reference if we see anything like this again.

Comment: Pekka, your were exactly right.  If you submit that as an answer I will give you the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though acrobat reader is keeping the pdf file open on you

http://acrobatusers.com/forum/javascript/closing-pdf-doc-javascript

I found a previous post that checks to see if the window is null rather then checking to see if it is closed (if the window isnt null then we know it is open) [how to close a browser having pdf inside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649367/how-to-close-a-browser-having-pdf-inside-it) not sure if that will help your problem

The other solution i found was to use an iframe like already stated.

http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/148260-pdf-popup-close-button